# How can I update a row based on id in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I am new in hibernate. I am using SesssionFactory to get the session of the transaction and one way which I found after searching is used for setting few fields using set parameter i.e

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
    "UPDATE table_name set field1=:f1 where ID=:id");

query.setParameter("f1", f1);
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

but I want to update the whole row. I have already set the values in the entity class but is there a way to pass the values of the whole entity class to the database based on the id the id is the primary key for the table which I want to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you already have all data present in the hibernate entity object? Then just call the session directly:

```
getCurrentSession().save(myEntity);
```

to create a new object, or

```
getCurrentSession().update(myEntity);
```

to update an existing row.

If not sure, you can use:

```
getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(myEntity);
```

Comment: AFAIK, if you got the object from the database any changes made to it are automatically persisted when the session is closed, i.e. it's not necessary to call `getCurrentSession().update(myEntity);`

Comment: will it check the criteria that update that row in the table based on id

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Session#update](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#update(java.lang.Object)) (or saveOrUpdate). This will allow you to persist a complete, mapped, object to the database.

Comment: but then will it check the criteria that update that row in the table based on id

Comment: Calling `session.update(entity)` will issue an SQL statement along the lines of `UPDATE table SET field1 = :field1Value, ... WHERE id = :id`. So if by 'check criteria' you mean filter by the record identifier. then yes.

Answer (score 0):

To be as OO as you can, you can get entity by  session.get(entityClass, id);
And then after modifying object by setters/getters, you can save it back to the DB using update method :session.update(entity);